# Strange behavior with cfdisk and GPT

Tags: partitioning, gpt

I had a few partitions in a GPT disk and needed to create a small, 2MB partition in the beginning (problems with Grub). The first partition was already small, just 200MB (for /boot) and fully backed up, easy to restore, so I deleted /dev/sdb1 and turned it into 2 partitions.

First problem: as soon as I deleted that 200MB partition, cfdisk reported 1.9T free space. That just made no sense.

But I went ahead. I created a 2MB partition as sdb1 and a 198MB as... well, cfdisk assigned sdb7 to it, after all other partitions.

I didn't like it, but then I used gdisk to sort all partitions and everything now looks right: sdb1 is 2MB and sdb2 is 198MB. Except that cfdisk reports 908GB of free space at the end of the disk, in purple (everything else on the screen is white). There should be no free space. Everything is used.

I rebooted, and cfdisk still reports 908GB of free space. That is creeping me out. What is going on?

Comment: Do other tools report it (gdisk in particular)? Is this a 32bit OS? The GPT support in util-linux cfdisk is relatively young.

Comment: I see nothing unusual with gdisk or gparted. It's just cfdisk. I have mounted the other partitions and they all work. I am just... erm, apprehensive.

Comment: How about regular `fdisk`? But specifically, I would trust that if **gdisk** says it's correct, then it's correct. (It has verification options in menus.) It's been around for a very long time.

Comment: And finally, what version of cfdisk do you have?

Comment: Nothing unusual in fdisk -l either.
My cfdisk is version 2.25.2. BTW, it's 64bit Debian Jessie.

Comment: Boot and install in UEFI mode and you won't need any additional partition.

Comment: What is 'UEFI mode' and how do I enable it?

Comment: Try the `v` command in both `gdisk` and `fdisk`. In both programs, this command initiates a check of the partition table data structures, so any problems that don't create in-your-face errors should be highlighted. As the programs are unrelated, it's conceivable that one might notice a problem that the other would miss, and that might be causing the `sfdisk` weirdness you're seeing.